# $x^x$ for non-positive values of $x$

Tags: graphing-functions

Mathcad, Wolfram, Google, and a couple of online graphing engines all indicate that $x^x$ is undefined for non-positive values of $x$. But isn't $x^x$ defined for negative integers? Eg. $(-3)^{-3} = -(\frac{1}{27})$, isn't it? What am I missing here?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem occurs when you try to take even roots of negative numbers.  For instance $(-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is undefined over the real numbers.

Comment: But (-1)^(-1/2) isn't a value of x^x. In any case, if x^x is undefined for ALL non-positive x, then how do we explain (-3)^(-3) ?

Comment: It'd be $e^{x\log x}$ which is defined for $x>0$.

Comment: Well, isn't that like saying the graph of y=x is defined only for x>0 since e^(ln x) is defined only for x>0 ?

Comment: It is defined for negative integers, and for negative rational fractions for which the denominator is odd, but it isn't defined on any continuous environment.

Comment: My copy of Mathcad 15, and various online graphing engines like http://www.google.com.sg/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=graph+x%5Ex+domain#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=graph+x%5Ex+&pbx=1&oq=graph+x%5Ex+&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1803l1803l0l2052l1l1l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=fc9ce17ab512803c&biw=1111&bih=574 are adamant that x^x is undefined for non-positive x. I guess we really do have to use judgement and common sense when using computers to do maths then. :) Thanks all for your input!

Comment: Read my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/what-is-lim-limits-x-to-0-x-frac12x/37443#37443 I think it may be useful.

Comment: @Ryan: Just make it $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certainly $(-3)^{-3}$ has a well-defined value.

The basic problem here is that an expression such as "$x^x$" is actually *not enough to define a function*. One also needs to a specification of which domain the values of $x$ can be drawn from.

Many school systems place great value on teaching their students to find the greatest subset of the reals for which the expression has a value, and call that *the* domain of the expression, but it is not a universal mathematical law that this has to be true. (In fact, mathematicians tend to scoff at the idea that $\mathbb R$ should have such a favored status that it is the largest subset of *it* that becomes "the" domain of an expression).

What computer mathematics systems such as the ones you've tried do when you present them with a naked expression such as $x^x$ is to try to *guess* which domain you could have had in mind for them. Rather than the *largest* set of numbers that the expression makes sense for, they usually try to guess at the *nicest* set, for some not really well defined sense of "nicest". And sets such as $(0,\infty)$ is generally considered more likely than $(0,\infty)\cup\mathbb Z$, if only because the union between a continuous set and a discrete one looks like there will be few or no interesting properties in common between the two parts.

However, *mathematically* you're certainly free to define a function $f$ such that $f(x)=x^x$ for $x\in(0,\infty)\cup\mathbb Z$ if you want to.

Comment: Thank you Henning for your excellent and satisfying elucidation! I've just went back to my Mathcad and explicitly set the range of x to include the negative integers, and indeed, the graph now reflects the values I was initially expecting. How would I cope without this forum? haha

Comment: @Ryan: It's not a forum, this is a Q&A site which is exactly what makes it lovely.